# What is the way to get solution time with gurobi via Python API?

Tags: python, gurobi

When I use `gurobi` python api to solve LP with interior point methods, I can not get the solution time. Does anyone have any idea? Is there any hard command that requires the code to return that time?

Answer (score 2):

The runtime of Gurobi can be queried using the [Runtime attribute](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/runtime.html). In Python, this is simply

```
model.Runtime
```

Please make sure, to query the runtime right after the optimization is done - in some cases, it can happen that it is reset, e.g. when updating the model.